# How can I get "price"s value in this dict list?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

```
products = [
        {"name": "samsung s6", "price": 3000},
        {"name": "samsung s7", "price": 4000},
        {"name": "samsung s8", "price": 5000},
        {"name": "samsung s9", "price": 6000},
        {"name": "samsung s10", "price": 7000}
        ]
for product in products:
    for a, b in product.items():
        print(b)
```

hey guys. i want to get price key's value and calculate total price all of items i have. what's the best way to get it?

Comment: `sum(d["price"] for d in products)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value of each dict's price key, simply access it using the `my_dict["key"]` syntax. Here is a basic way to sum the prices using a for loop:

```py
total = 0
for product in products:
    total += product["price"]
print(total)
```

The slightly more advanced method is to create a sequence of prices using a list comprehension or generator expression, and pass it to the built-in `sum` function, like this:

```py
total = sum(product["price"] for product in products)
```

Comment: You're referring to an answer that has been deleted. I suggest that you put the for loop in your own answer.

Comment: It returns:3000
7000
12000
18000
25000 is there any way to show only total price?

Comment: @leskof That was just printing each price to show you how to access them. See my edit for the actual summation.

Comment: Yeah thanks for advices. This is still returns 5 times of "25000" but okay it's the actual total price.

Answer (score 0):

The short version:

```py
print( sum( x['price'] for x in products ) )
```

This is the same as:

```py
newList = []
for x in products:
    newList.append( x['price'] )
out = sum( newList )
print( out )
```

Comment: That would work, although I think it is generally better to use a generator expression rather than construct a temporary list.

Comment: @alani At the time you commented, a generator expression was the only thing in my post, so I don't know what you mean.

Comment: No, your short version uses a list comprehension. You are creating a temporary list and then discarding it after you have summed the elements.

Comment: Look at my edits, the short version is the original. I edited in the long version so the short version was easier to understand.

Comment: Yes I know, and the argument to `sum` is a list comprehension. It is not doing the same thing under the hood as in the generator expression in Andrew Eckart's answer. See the extra `[` ... `]` that you have in the syntax.

Comment: Ah, the miscommunication here was that I did not know there was a difference between a list comprehension and a generator expression in this case. Thank you for the comment, its helpful.